# How is the definition syntax of typedef of basic_module_directory for the 1.9.xx version of STLSoft

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, stl

I has been migrating to 2013 version of Visual Studio a STL project, that was create on old version visual studio. It was developed with a lot of libraries,  one of them is STLSoft that make changes, my problem is when i try to do this:

```
  #include <winstl/module_directory.hpp>
  typedef winstl_ns_qual(basic_module_directory)<TCHAR>  module_directory;
```

The compiles give me a error on typedef line, because `module_diretory.hpp` change, before it was a class, now have other strucure.
My question is what is the way to do this `typedef`?

**EDIT**
Compiler says:

```
error C2039: 'basic_module_directory' : is not a member of'stlsoft::winstl_project'
error C2143: syntax error : fault ';' before of '<'
error C4430: type specifier isnt there; hope int . Note: C++ did not admit default int
```

**Please somebody help me!**

Comment: Please include the exact text of any error messages you have encountered.

Comment: Read the error, there is no `basic_module_directory`. Looking at their  [documentation](http://www.stlsoft.org/doc-1.9/group__group____library____system.html), it is just completely broken. Considering STLSoft says it hasn't been maintained since 2009, I'd say just trash the whole thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the class template is renamed to `moddir_policy.` They have a similar typedef:

[`typedef stlsoft_ns_qual(special_string_instance_1)<moddir_policy<TCHAR> >          module_directory;`](http://www.stlsoft.org/doc-1.9/module__directory_8hpp-source.html)

So you can use the following typedef:

```
typedef winstl_ns_qual(module_directory)          module_directory;
```

or

```
using winstl_ns_qual(module_directory);
```

or even

```
using module_directory = winstl_ns_qual(module_directory);
```